# Expose type constructor in module without duplication

Tags: ocaml

So I have the following module:

```ml
module MyMod : sig
    type t = A | B
    val foo : t -> int
end = struct
    type t = A | B
    let bar x = x * x
    let foo = function 
        | A -> bar 2
        | B -> bar 3
end
```

I need type `t` to be concrete (publicly exposed) so I can use it from outside the module scope:

```ml
# MyMod.foo MyMod.A;;
- : int = 4
# MyMod.foo MyMod.B;;
- : int = 9
```

However, this requires that I duplicate the constructor definition in both the `sig` and the `struct`. Is there a smarter way to do this without duplicating the constructor definition?

Answer (score 3):

You can define the type in a third module, and include that in both the structure and signature.

```
module T = struct
  type t = A | B
end

module MyMod : sig
  include module type of T
  val foo : t -> int
end = struct
  include T
  let bar x = x * x
  let foo = function 
    | A -> bar 2
    | B -> bar 3
end
```

Comment: Would you consider this idiomatic?

Comment: No, not really, because it significantly hurts readability for some minor convenience when writing. In functor-heavy code, which exacerbates this kind of duplication, you can see this technique used in what's called [the _intf trick](https://www.craigfe.io/posts/the-intf-trick/). I wouldn't call that idiomatic either, but it's definitely a style.